# Is there a way to overlap different time time graphs in grafana using datasource as OpenTSDB

Tags: monitoring, grafana, opentsdb

We are using grafana to display graphs over OpenTSDB for our performance test results, so we have a use case in which we would like to compare a test metrics with benchmark results or different timestamp, so is there a way we can compare?
i know it is possible with Grafite datasource using timeshift function but now sure about OpenTSDB.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this plugin "[graph-compare-panel](https://github.com/AutohomeCorp/graph-compare-panel/tree/master)". It's very easy to use, but it only support some versions of Grafana .
[image]

Comment: awesome. have been looking for this for ages.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, this is fairly easy to accomplish in [ATSD](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) which supports opentsdb protocol and provides a storage plugin for Grafana.

https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/baselines/

`time-offset = 1 week`

Here's another [example](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/3f33d4ba/16/#), a bit more artistic:

[image: offset]

A more advanced example is to overlay multiple series using a relative elapsed time. Don't know if this is relevant for your use case, but we're working on it.

Disclaimer: I work for the company developing Axibase Time Series Database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a timeshift function for OpenTSDB. The issue for the timeshift [feature request](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/issues/175) has been closed and [this commit](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/commit/c7dee0184bbc89aa90b7688c6224ca6cf3a2430d) adds the timeShift/shift function.

On the other hand, the function is undocumented and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/issues/965) where it doesn't seem to work.